# How to fix selenium and python interpreter path

Tags: python-3.x, windows, selenium, visual-studio-code

Recently changed from Linux to Windows, but I am having trouble with the interpreter and selenium or VS code.

Whenever I try to run a code that worked on my Mac and linux machine, it gives me errors on windows, what can I do?

```
    PS C:\Users\xdmoj> & C:/Users/xdmoj/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.7.exe c:/Users/xdmoj/Dropbox/python/Projects/typings.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/xdmoj/Dropbox/python/Projects/typings.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\xdmoj\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\xdmoj\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 1207, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: What is `PATH` ? Please share your entire method in which you are getting exception

Comment: PATH is for where the chrome web driver is, but I don't think that is the issue. It's the interpreter path that it uses, I try to change it to python 3.9.6 but when I download selenium it says that it has already been downloaded on 3.7.2, how do I download it on version 3.9.6.

Comment: Which python version you are using `3.7.2` or `3.9.6` ?

Comment: 3.7.2 when using selenium

Comment: Can you please supply `PATH`? That is the line that is raising an exception. If there was a problem with the interpreter path it wouldn't have even been able to raise an exception.

Comment: PATH = "C:/Users/xdmoj/Dropbox/python/Selenium/chromedriver"

Comment: And is `chromedriver` here the `exe`? when you enter `C:/Users/xdmoj/Dropbox/python/Selenium/chromedriver.exe` into command prompt does anything happen?

Comment: Actually, that specific error occurs if you don't unzip the `chromedriver` zip.

Comment: omg, I was being stupid, that was the version for linux, thanks bro, really made my day

Comment: No problem. I highly recommend enabling file extension view in the Windows 10 file explorer view tab if you haven't already. It'll save you from a lot of problems like this.